# Flutter: To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if these plugins support the Android V2 embedding

Tags: flutter

So I upgraded my Flutter version to "2.5.3" and since then my code stop running and when I run it I get the error that says: `` The plugins `flutter_custom_dialog, flutter_webview_plugin, libphonenumber, permission, shared_preferences, simple_rsa, url_launcher` use a deprecated version of the Android embedding. To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if these plugins support the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing them since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs. If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration. `` And then the run will stop and I will get further error like `146:15: Error: The method 'setMockMethodCallHandler' isn't defined for the class 'MethodChannel'.` and with addition below error: ``` FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/Users/mickeymuller/Downloads/fluttersdk/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1005
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command '/Users/mickeymuller/Downloads/fluttersdk/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 31s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 ```

Comment: Have you updated that plugins? I have the same problem with two widgets but only is a warning, it build correctly for me.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So I was able to resolve this issue by downgrading my Flutter version to a version below 2.5 because finding shows that versions from 2.5 encounter this error. To download for mac here is the link : [enter link description here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=macos)

Window: [enter link description here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=windows)

Answer (score 2):

You may already have found your answer,still I provide a solution for this problem for others, who might have the same problem.

If you don't have added code to
`android/app/src/main/java/[your/package/name]/MainActivity.java`

1. Go to `android/app/src/main/java/co/<XXXX>/<YYYY>/MainActivity.java`
2. remove all of the imports
3. add the following line to the imports:

   `import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;`
4. delete all of the contents inside the MainActivity Block, so your file looks like this:

   `import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;  public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {}`
5. Open `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.`
6. replace `android:name` with `android:name="${applicationName}"`
7. Remove all `<meta-data>` tags with key `android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame".`
8. Add the following above the `<intent-filter>` the following code:

   `<meta-data android:name="flutterEmbedding" android:value="2" />`

   `<meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable" android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />`
9. try to build your app

If you have added code to the `mainActivity.java` or want to know more about it visit this [post](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects) which is also the source of my solution.
There's also a nice youtube video demonstrating this solution, you can watch it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qu7afHmErAs&ab_channel=CodingWay)